# Need to align the div element in style sheet at the center of the page

Tags: html, css

The webpage displays four arrows top, right, left and bottom; at the top left corner of the screen. I need to align them at the center of the page such that it fits to the page layout without scrolling appearing. Can anyone suggest what I need to do?

Please see the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes"/>
<style>
   #item_1 {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-left: 25px solid transparent;
   border-right: 25px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 50px solid #555;  
   }

    #item_2 {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid #555;
    margin-top: 50px;
    }


    #item_3 {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid #555;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float:left;
    }

    #item_4 {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    align : right;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid #555;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    }  
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="float:left; width: 100%">
    <div id="item_3"></div>
    <div style="float:left">
    <div id="item_1"></div>
    <div id="item_2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_4"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" style="
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    ">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better not using float, but use position:fixed; with top and left values.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp#:~:targetText=An%20element%20with%20position%3A%20fixed,would%20normally%20have%20been%20located.

Answer (score 0):

You might try putting/grouping all of the 4 arrow divs in one single div and do styling on that. I have tried the following code:

CSS

```
  .container
    {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

HTML

```
   <div class="container">
        <div style="float:left; width: 100%">
        <div id="item_3" ></div>
        <div style="float:left">
        <div id="item_1"></div>
        <div id="item_2"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="item_4"></div>
        </div>
   </div>
```